# Index with Many Indices

Tags: scala

Is there a quick scala idiom to have retrieve multiple elements of a a traversable using indices.

I am looking for something like

```
 val L=1 to 4 toList
 L(List(1,2)) //doesn't work
```

I have been using `map` so far, but wondering if there was a more "scala" way

```
List(1,2) map {L(_)}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Since a `List` is a `Function` you can write just

```
List(1,2) map L
```

Although, if you're going to be looking things up by index, you should probably use an `IndexedSeq` like `Vector` instead of a `List`.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an [implicit class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) that adds the functionality:

```
implicit class RichIndexedSeq[T](seq: IndexedSeq[T]) {
  def apply(i0: Int, i1: Int, is: Int*): Seq[T] = (i0+:i1+:is) map seq
}
```

You can then use the sequence's `apply` method with one index or multiple indices:

```
scala> val data = Vector(1,2,3,4,5)
data: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> data(0)
res0: Int = 1

scala> data(0,2,4)
res1: Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Since `Vector` implements the `IndexedSeq` trait, I changed the class to enrich the trait itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `for` comprehension but it's no clearer than the code you have using `map`.

```
scala> val indices = List(1,2)
indices: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> for (index <- indices) yield L(index)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

I think the most readable would be to implement your own function `takeIndices(indices: List[Int])` that takes a list of indices and returns the values of a given `List` at those indices. e.g.

```
L.takeIndices(List(1,2))
List[Int] = List(2,3)
```

Comment: I was going to write that :P